# Add Different Text to an Existing Div each time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to jquery and am trying to code this where each time you click on the content, the content is added to an existing div. However, the content will be constantly changing. I tried making it a variable, but it is still not working. Any help or advice is appreciated.

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tU2En/7/

html:

```
<button id="Add">Add Text</button>


<div id="content">
    <p>Content 1</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
    var text='#content p';
    $(function () {

      $('#Add').on('click', function () {
        $('text').appendTo('#content');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$('text').appendTo('#content');
```

to:

```
$(text).appendTo('#content');
```

By quoting `text`, you're treating it as a string and jQuery is looking for an element named text.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tU2En/9/)**